# Adjust Bootstrap width, but keep container class constraints

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have a major style change whereas when all my views were originally setup I had used Bootstrap and relied on the container class to adjust for media queries at breakpoints of 1200px, 992px, and 768px. All my form input and other content work their padding and all off of the container for paddings, margins, etc... Now, it is requested that the width be 100%, but all the content to stay where it is so that the background colors styling fills the width of display.

I was trying to think of how I can add another container class to make this work over all of the views. What are some recommendations on this with keeping the constraints of content to the 1200px and so on (for media queries and such), but make the other areas spread to that 100%?

Here is an image capture of it now. It is just the tan and dark gray area with the topo image that would expand 100% while all else stays within constraints of container class.

[image]

And my code is structured as so you can see where my delima is with over-riding bootstraps container class:

```
<div class="container">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="naviaHead col-md-12">
            <div class="naviaHeader">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="col-md-6 loginArea">
                        <h1 class="col-md-8">Login</h1>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8 naviaInp">
                                <input type="text" name="userName" class="form-control" placeholder="username" data-ng-model="loginData.userName"autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8 naviaInp">
                                <input type="password" name="passWord" class="form-control" placeholder="password" data-ng-model="loginData.password">
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear: both;">
                                <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" data-ng-click="login()" value="login">
                                <div data-ng-hide="message == ''" class="alert alert-danger">
                                    {{message}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="loginForget">
                                <span><a class="naviaLink" href="#/logreg/forgotUser">forgot username</a> or <a class="naviaLink" href="#/logreg/forgotPass">forgot password</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sowLogin">
                                <img class="col-md-3" src="ppt/assets/images/login/sowIcon.svg">
                                <p class="col-md-9"><a class="naviaLink" href="https://pebb.flex-plan.com/part/PortalRegistration.aspx">PEBB eligible State of Washington employees please click here to access the portal</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img style="padding-left: 25%;" src="ppt/assets/images/login/naviaLogo.png">
                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="loginLearn">
        <div id="area1" class="col-md-4 learnSections">
            <img src="ppt/assets/images/login/teaserImage1-full.png">
            <div class="learnText">
                <h3 class="teaserTitle">Online Account Access</h3>
                <p class="teaserText">24/7 Access to balances, claim submissions and all things Navia!</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary learnButtons">learn more</button>
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div id="area2" class="col-md-4 learnSections">
            <img src="ppt/assets/images/login/teaserImage2-full.png">
            <div class="learnText">
                <h3 style="margin-top: 0;" class="teaserTitle">Navia Benefits Card</h3>
                <p class="teaserText">Don't wait for reimbursement!</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary learnButtons">learn more</button>
            </div>        
        </div>    
        <div id="area3" class="col-md-4 learnSections">
            <img src="ppt/assets/images/login/teaserImage3-full.png">
            <div class="learnText">
                <h3 style="margin-top: 0;" class="teaserTitle">FlexConnect</h3>
                <p class="teaserText">Link your FSA to your insurnace and file claims instantly!</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary learnButtons">learn more</button>
            </div>        
        </div>    
    </div> 
    <div style="background-color: #ede8e2; height: 150px; clear: both;">
        <!-- intentionally blank -->
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: You can override any bootstrap class with our custom property. Another way is to add your custom classes to element that you want to override.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will solve your purpose

```
 <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:red;">//This will be 100% width

        <div class="container">//Inside this put your content as it was to make it indent as previous
         //Your page HTML here
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks...forgot about that. It works, but can be a pain when you got complex headers with multiple container classes now.